# Oauth2 in Go with Martini - ResponseWriter syntax for Reddit

Tags: oauth, go

I have been banging my head for two days on this and am clearly missing something. I am a bit of a doofus on backend/server development and hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

- I have a desktop application (not Go) which makes an OAuth2 request from Reddit.
- The OAuth2 in my application is working just fine however the flow fails when Reddit hit the redirect URI on my own server.
- I am guessing it is waiting for the proper ResponseWriter result and none of my dozen incompetent attempts have worked.
- The redirect URI hits my server and callback function (below) then does nothing.

**Questions**

- Where am I going wrong?
- Is variable "t" my auth code and am I done (aka, you are a buffoon!)?
- Can I just write t's value to my non-Go app and be done?
- Or am I missing a step?
- Note: code slightly simplified.

Thanks!

```
package main

import (
    "code.google.com/p/goauth2/oauth"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/codegangsta/martini"
    "io"
    "net/http"
)

var config = &oauth.Config{
    ClientId:     CLIENT_ID,
    ClientSecret: CLIENT_SECRET,
    Scope:        "identify",
    AuthURL:      "https://ssl.reddit.com/api/v1/authorize",
    TokenURL:     "https://ssl.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token",
    RedirectURL:  "http://localhost:3000/reddit_oauth",
}

func main() {
    m := martini.Classic()
    m.Get("/reddit_oauth", handleCallback)
    m.Run()
}

func handleCallback(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    //Get the code from the response
    code := r.FormValue("code")

    // Exchange the received code for a token
    t := &oauth.Transport{Config: config}
    t.Exchange(code)

    // Am I done?
}
```

**Points of reference**

- Reddit API

  - https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/API
- Reddit specific PHP example

  - https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/OAuth2-PHP-Example
- Reddit specific Python example

  - https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/OAuth2-Python-Example
- Martini

  - https://github.com/codegangsta/martini
- Go OAuth2

  - https://code.google.com/p/goauth2/
  - https://code.google.com/p/goauth2/source/browse/oauth/oauth.go

**Misc**

- Why Martini? It looks bloody great.
- Why not just Oauth2? Because I am ignorant.
- Why not PHP/Python? Because, c'mon! I am trying to learn Go. (I am loving it and getting some great results which enhances my UI work.)

Comment: `t.Exchange(code)` returns the auth token and an error - check their value.

Comment: Also see here for a more complete example: https://code.google.com/p/goauth2/source/browse/oauth/example/oauthreq.go

Comment: Thanks for the leads. I will have a look and take another crack.

Comment: I may have found the issue. I'll post a follow up if so.

Comment: It isn't exactly the answer I was expecting, however I'm getting results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, the answer mostly sat in my client application--again, not Go--which had a few missing aspects in its OAuth2 request. (It also took a little effort to get the headers correct for the different requests.)

The best info for Reddit's OAuth2 process I found was here: http://www.reddit.com/r/redditdev/comments/197x36/using_oauth_to_send_valid_requests/

The response from Reddit still pings me asking for the ClientID and ClientSecret, which I am sure could be served via a proper ResponseWriter, though for the moment I am simply copy/pasting into a popup just so I can focus on something else!

When I get that squared away I will add to this answer.

If anyone is interested in any more information, please do not hesitate to ask.

Thanks again, TomWilde and Elithrar!

Comment: Another day of struggle revealed the issue: an error handler was constantly overwriting the results from the success handler.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the martini-contrib page for [an OAuth2 implementation.](https://github.com/martini-contrib/oauth2)